# How to get mongodb_url output from terminal

Tags: mongodb, heroku

First time using MONGODB on a MEAN application, i need to find out the mongodb url string to add it in my server.js file. I tried heroku config | grep MONGODB_URI, but it shows no output. How should i be doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the mLab add-on installed and then you should be able to get the connection string using the following command:

`$ heroku config:get MONGODB_URI`

Source: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab#getting-your-connection-uri

Comment: meh you're right, i've added the mlab,  but didnt notice it failed because i dont have credit card added to my heroku account ¬¬